# Where can I find template for Social networking site (paid or free doesn't matter) for my java website?

Tags: template

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where could I buy a “social networking” html template or psd/ai file?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10226/where-could-i-buy-a-social-networking-html-template-or-psd-ai-file)

Hi can you tell me any website where  I can find a template for my Social networking site (paid or free doesn't matter) in java ?

I browsed joomla and drupal but they are in PHP. Please tell me if there is any place where i can find java site templates

Answer (score -1):

Site template and software are very different things.  Sounds like you're actually wanting social networking software app that is written in java.  This site may help you: http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/java-open-source-social-network